# Multi-Dimensional Array(or other structure) in Java

Tags: java, arrays, spring-boot, multidimensional-array

I come from PHP, i'm developping a tool, and i need to use a multidimensional array ( or something other, map,..)
My goal is to be able to have an ArrayList like that :

```
[["name1", "surname1", "age"], ["name1", "surname1", "age"]]
Or :
[["name" : "name1", "surname" : "surname1", "age" : "age1"], ["name" : "name2", "surname" : "surname2", "age" : "age2"]]
```

And to be able to add another list into this global list, without size limit.
Actually, i do not found that in Java, it's crazy xD.

The goal after that it to filter (with something like in PHP ((multi sort) to be able to sort those arrays which areinside the global array.

( I need to sort a key of those list,in order to get the most recent, and then i save the first list which is the most recent ).

So actually, i only arrive to get an arraylist.. but not multidimensionnal..

Thanks for tips :)
(I use spring boot )

EDIT 1 :

```
HashMap<String, String> myhash = new HashMap<String, String>();
        myhash.put("Cat1", "james");
        myhash.put("Cat2", "adams");
        myhash.put("Cat3", "turk");
        System.out.println(myhash);
        // {Cat3=turk, Cat2=adams, Cat1=james}
        // I Would like : [{Cat3=turk, Cat2=adams, Cat1=james}, {Cat3=turkother, Cat2=adamsother, Cat1=jamesother}, {Cat3=fred, Cat2=ded, Cat1=tp}]
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking--a `List`'s elements can be anything, including other `List`s. Same with arrays. It also sounds like you want a LIFO.

Comment: If you want each "array" to have named attributes such as `surname`, you better create a custom class which has those attributes. You can then create an ArrayList from those objects.

Comment: I would like to be able to create a list of list :)
Like in PHP :) 
So a 2 dimensions list :) ( like if i was doing list[1][2] in php )

Comment: You can have an ArrayList of ArrayLists. `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer> > aList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer> >(10); ` , for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>` and than use filter on the `HashMap.keyset()`.

But don't know if this is exactly what your are looking for.

Two notes:

1. This is basic Java. No Spring required.
2. If you make a nice Java object with the properties you are looking for, perhaps filtering will be more easier... But don't know. I would create an object `Person` with the required properties, store it in an `ArraysList` and than use this object further.

Update:

```
    HashMap<String, String> myhash = new HashMap<String, String>();
    myhash.put("Cat1", "james");
    myhash.put("Cat2", "adams");
    myhash.put("Cat3", "turk");
    System.out.println(myhash);
    // {Cat3=turk, Cat2=adams, Cat1=james}
    // I Would like : [{Cat3=turk, Cat2=adams, Cat1=james}, {Cat3=turk, Cat2=adams, Cat1=james}]

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> lst = new ArrayList<>();
    lst.add(myhash);
    lst.add(myhash);
    System.out.println(lst); //[{Cat3=turk, Cat2=adams, Cat1=james}, {Cat3=turk, Cat2=adams, Cat1=james}]
```

Remark:

1. take care that `myhash` is added twice ==> if you change on the one field ==> changes on the other field is done as well
2. I don't see much value in this sample. Especially since the Map is added twice.
3. Take a look at the different samples for streams - for filtering and sorting. This might be useful.
4. If there are more qs I would guess its better to create a different q. I think that's it ... Feel free to ask ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i would like to use map as you suggested, can you explain me how i can do what i want ? ( i have edited the post )

Comment: I posted a wrong example, i would like values which are different. I tested to `lst.clear()` and then put other values, but it doesn't works

Comment: Would you mind to update your sample? I have no clue what are really longing for.

Comment: The "would like" has been edited :)
I do not want to have to create other object name (ie : no creation of other list )

Comment: But as I mentioned in the beginning. The values are than an `ArrayList<String>` - which means they are dynamically for adding more values. As far as I understand you, you want to have 3 values fixed. If so than you could use as values as well the type `String[]`. And than iterate over the columns (`3`) and each time over the `keys()` and take from the there `value[columnIndex]`

Comment: I want to be able to add different values into it.
Actually, i need to use new on the list each time.

This code will be in a `for` so i'm not able to use fixed name.
I need a code that will not duplicate the content of the object list created before.

Comment: But than the sample starts to get strange. Sorry... If you want to have a dynamic list of items than the resultset will have as well a dynamic list of items. To my understanding they are fixed. Anyway if you use Spring and return them for a request ==> Spring will transform the list of objects automatically for you. All you have to do is to create a proper list of objects. I'll leave it up to you how to construct them.

Comment: Actually i'm creating a class object, the goal, is to create an array of those object.
I need to create for each `for` a new object. 
And to put this object into a List.

And my problem is in the creation of the new object that need a new name each time..

Comment: It's ok, i found a solution, i put objects in a arraylist, and i think it will be ok

Comment: Great that you managed it. I think at the beginning there is always a learning curve. Depends how steep it'll finally be. Anyway good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you have a list of lists in Java.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> myList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! But i think i will prefer to use HashMap as suggested. I appreciate your answer